# Can write DAL parameter collection from stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Is there some way that I can get parameter collection code in C# to be used in DAL by running a stored procedure ? please help.

Comment: I am using Ado.net and DAL method will  returned datatable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters()`.  ( It also works in the latest Oracle drivers )

It will load the parameters from the stored procedure into the `.Parameters` property of your DbCommand object and you can `foreach()` to loop through them to get the names, types, and directions...

Hope that's what you were looking for...